# If/Elseif Condition on a Dataframe combined with multiple actions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, if-statement

I have a dataframe object column which looks like 104.5 and always has a suffix like K, B or M standing for Kilo, Billions or Millions. For instance 104.5B.

What I would like to do is to check for the suffix and multiple the value by 10^3, 10^6 or 10^9 'inplace'.

I found some explanations for labeling a new column, but nothing like a multiplication in place. How am I doing it smart?

Comment: Hello - what have you tried already?  I would also help if you were to provide an example of your data for others to be able to see what you're seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dictionary and a map, like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Values': ['104.5B', '102.4K', '951M']})

multipliers = {'B': 1,
               'K': 1000,
               'M': 1000000}


df['Values'] = df['Values'].str[:-1].astype(float) * df['Values'].str[-1].map(multipliers)

print(df)
```

This prints:

```
        Values
0        104.5
1     102400.0
2  951000000.0
```

Comment: Great, thanks! :-) I'm gonna upvote you as soon as I'm allowed!